# Python during lts upgrade

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, package-management, python

I currently use the deadsnakes repo on my 14 LTS server for Python 3.5, in the coming weeks I plan to upgrade to 16 LTS and have official python 3.5 support. What should I do with my current package and repo? I think if I leave everything as is and perform the upgrade to 16 LTS it should ignore the distro 3.5 and keep my version from the repo.

Extra: I needed Python 3.5 for a discord bot I wrote and want to maintain the code. Should I keep dead snakes and ignore the distro version?